# Install of ros-fuerte-camera1394 fails on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros, camera1394, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I'm trying to install the camera1394 package on my fuerte intallation on Ubuntu 12.04 but I'm running into dependency problems.

The problem is that the ros-fuerte-camera1394 package (in the ROS Ubuntu repository) depends on a package called libdc1394-22-dev. This package comes from the ROS package repository but unfortunately it conflicts with the libdc1394-22 package from the official Ubuntu repository. That package then is a dependency for a huge number (200+) of other packages so removing it is not really an option.

So my question is basically whether this is something that is being solved or is there some workaround for this?

Best regards,
Stefán Freyr.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34153/install-of-ros-fuerte-camera1394-fails-on-ubuntu-12.04/) by [StFS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2394/stfs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 182 on 2012-05-16

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-16**:
I'll take a look. Sounds like a debbuild problem. It should be using the system libdc1394.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-16**:
I checked on my Fuerte laptop. It seems to use the system versions of libdc1394-22 and libdc1394-22-dev. I wonder what is different for you?

**Comment by [StFS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2394/stfs/) on 2012-05-16**:
Hi again. Sorry I seem to have misunderstood what I saw in aptitude.

**Comment by [StFS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2394/stfs/) on 2012-05-16**:
So here's the deal. I just tried installing the ros-fuerte-camera1394 package using "apt-get" and everything went fine, no errors appeared. However if I open aptitude there are errors and it suggests 242 removals. After drilling down a bit it looks like the culprit is libraw1394-tools (to be contd.)

**Comment by [StFS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2394/stfs/) on 2012-05-16**:
The error I'm getting is "Some dependencies of libraw1394-tools are not satisfied: libraw1394-tools breaks libraw1394-dev (<= 2.0.7-1ubuntu1)"

Is this a dependency problem in the official Ubuntu repository?

**Comment by [StFS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2394/stfs/) on 2012-05-16**:
OK, it seems that this is an Ubuntu dependency problem:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libraw1394/+bug/974504

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out that this is actually a confirmed Ubuntu repo dependency problem:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libraw1394/+bug/974504

Edit: It looks like this can be "resolved" by running aptitude with the -R flag and installing the ros-fuerte-camera1394 package that way. Then, aptitude will not try to install the recommended packages as well and the next time aptitude is run it will not try installing it, even though it's run without the -R option.

---

Originally posted by [StFS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2394/stfs/) with karma: 182 on 2012-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2